# Can you help me to understand why this bind works?

Tags: c++, bind

I'm trying to understand bind and pre-fill functions in C++.

[Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9e2dba7a698e279) my example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

class Voice
{
public:
    double mValue;

private:
};

class VoiceManager
{
public:
    VoiceManager() { }
    ~VoiceManager() { }

    typedef std::function<void(Voice &)> VoiceChangerFunction;
    inline void UpdateVoices(VoiceChangerFunction callback) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mNumOfVoices; i++) {
            callback(mVoices[i]);
        }
    }
    static void SetValue(Voice &voice, unsigned int value) {
        voice.mValue = value;
        std::cout << voice.mValue << std::endl;
    }

private:
    static const int mNumOfVoices = 4;    
    Voice mVoices[mNumOfVoices];
};

int main()
{
    VoiceManager voiceManager;
    VoiceManager::VoiceChangerFunction callback;
    callback = std::bind(&VoiceManager::SetValue, std::placeholders::_1, 100);
    voiceManager.UpdateVoices(callback);
}
```

Basically, I create a `VoiceChangerFunction` function (object) that takes a `Voice &` as first parameter and returns `void`.

Later, I `bind` a function that will take as first parameter the one I'll give to it when I call it, and another parameter that I give when I bind it (`100`, in my example).

Right?

What I don't understand is: then, this function is passed to `UpdateVoices()`, which take as input a function/object that has 1 param (`Voice &`), not 2 as created in my bind function (`Voice &`, `unsigned int`).

How can it works?

Its like to have `void VoiceChangerFunction(Voice &voice)` and call `VoiceChangerFunction(Voice &voice, unsigned int value )`.

The function prototype is different. I mean: the callback `bind` I created isn't a `VoiceChangerFunctions` function, because **it takes more parameters**.

How can it works/match?

Comment: Why do you think your `bind()` result takes two parameters?

Comment: The new function created by bind takes _one_ parameter, because you have provided the other parameter for the function that the bind is based on. It's important to realise that bind creates a new function.

Comment: And where are "stored" those parameters? When it calls `callback(mVoices[i]);` it also pass 100 to SetValue().

Comment: @paizza In the object that bind returns.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: can you write down how will be "written" the object bind returns so? I don't get the point...

Comment: @paizza bind doesn't return a function pointer, it returns a std::function object. Like all objects in C++, this object can have member variables, and one of those member variables will be the bound parameter 100, which will be used when a function call is made via the function object.

Comment: The question's example code might benefit from further generalization. It was not as easy as it could have been to parse what you were trying to do with your code. Could just me though.

Answer (score 4):

That is exactly the beauty of `bind` and `std::function` at works. You are defining the callback as function taking one argument, and `bind` is  returning a function object which takes one argument.

The main point here is that it actually calls the function which takes 2 parameters, but the second one is fixed, and will always be 100 (in your case). This is the sole purpose of binders - to provide a way to call functions with different set of arguments with some fixed values. If you would be calling the function taking the same set of arguments, there would be no reason to use binders at all!

Knowing that `bind` is similar to lambdas, the same code could be written as - and probably be more clear:

```
VoiceManager::VoiceChangerFunction callback;
callback = [](Voice& v) { VoiceManager::SetValue(v, 100); };
voiceManager.UpdateVoices(callback);
```

And if you are curious how it works, you might try to create a binder framework yourself. If you are only doing it for educational purposes and not worried about too many details, it is not that hard.

Answer (score 2):

When you bind, you're making a new function that only takes `Voice` as a param, that's why it works.

```
void a_func(int x) { return; }
std::function<void(void)> new_func = std::bind(&a_func, 1);
```

`new_func` now has the signature of `void(void)`, so you could pass it around to anywhere that expects a function of type `void(void`).

When you call `new_func`, it really calls `a_func(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption about bind is wrong.
Your bind call returns a function object that will accept one parameter, namely the placeholder. The other parameter on your function is already bound to 100.

A little example:

```
void foo(int i1, int i2) {};
std::function<void(int,int)> fn1 = std::bind(foo, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
std::function<void(int)> fn1 = std::bind(foo, std::placeholders::_1, 1);
std::function<void()> fn1 = std::bind(foo, 1, 1);
```

The bind will create a matching function depending on bound and unbound parameters.

**Update**

The compiler will generate a struct from the bind expression and a copy of your parameter. Simplified something like this(this will not compile):

```
struct Function_{
    void(*fn)(Voice &, unsigned int)
    unsigned int i_;

    Function_(void(*f)(Voice &, unsigned int), unsigned int i):fn(f),i_(i){}
    void operator()(Voice& v){
        fn(v, i_);
    }
}
```

fn is the first parameter which is a function pointer and the bound (100) is the second. Then all you need is some type erasure and your own bind is ready to go.

Comment: What do you mean with "The other parmeter on your function is already bound to 100."? Where its stored the 100 value when I call that function? I don't think it replace `value` with 100, such as `voice.mValue = 100;` :O

Comment: @paizza: It's stored inside the mechanism of `bind`. This is what `bind` does! It binds.

Comment: @paizza I added a simplified sketch of what bind does but if you really want to know just look into boost. It is easier to read than the gcc STL code.